# Regex get first occurence with parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

> Adress: Big Avenue 9 - National (FOREST (THE)).

And i need parse it with regex to retrieve some data like this:

- Big Avenue 9 - National
- FOREST (THE)

I'm using this regex:

```
/Adress\:\s(.*(?!\.*\)))\((.*[\(.*\)]?)\)/
```

But they giveme this result:

- Big Avenue 9 - National (FOREST
- THE)

I've searching lot's information, but I don't know how can I do it.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What language and how are you actually searching?

Comment: Try [`Adress:\s*(.*?)\s*(\(.*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/oboNe3/1)

Comment: I'm using PHP and I'm searching like this:preg_match_all('/Adress\:\s(.*(?!\.*\)))\((.*[\(.*\)]?)\)/', $list->content, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. They work fine. I've change it to: `\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)` to exclude the parenthesis into the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~Adress:\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)~'
```

See the [PHP regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oboNe3/2), results

[image]

**Details**

- `Adress:` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as *many* as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/AZIsdI):

```
$re = '/Adress:\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)/';
$str = 'Adress: Big Avenue 9 - National (FOREST (THE)).';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match anything up to the first `(` by `([^(]*)` and then anything between the optional `(` ... `)` with `(\(.*\))?`

```
Adress\:\s([^(]*)(\(.*\))?
```

Play here: https://regexr.com/3kp5i